# Integrating dropdown menu of different views options on a page

Tags: 7, views

I have one content type called 'images' - at the moment they are just displayed as a list. However I want the users to have some options on how to view those images.

What I have done:
I have created 3 different Views that have different slideshow settings

What I need help with:
I need to have these 3 options appear automatically when any node from that content type is viewed as a dropdown with label: "View images as:"

**Most importantly the different views need to be generated programmatically using the images on that node and not by creating 3 slideshow for each image page!!!**

Answer (score 1):

there is no option in views to expose any changer for 3 different blocks, one thing you can do is make a drop-down and show/hide views using javascript/jQuery or make single unformatted view and change format using js/css on dropdown change.(you need to make some custom codes.)